# ANTLR Lexer fails when parsing C code with preprocessor directives

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grammar, lexer

We're using the ObjectiveC preprocessor [parser](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/objc/two-step-processing/ObjectiveCPreprocessorParser.g4) and [lexer](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/objc/two-step-processing/ObjectiveCPreprocessorLexer.g4) grammars for parsing directives in C code like `#define`, `#include`, `#ifndef`, etc. Below are relevant portions of the grammar (shortened for brevity).

```
file: text* EOF ;

text: code 
    | '#' directive (NEW_LINE | EOF) ;

code: CODE+ ;

directive
    : 'include' 
    | 'define' SYMBOL
    | 'ifndef' ;

SHARP:  '#' ;  
CODE:  ~[#'"/]+ ;
```

The code we're parsing is Pro*C - a dialect of C from Oracle but it's essentially C99 with embedded SQL. We parse and evaluate the directives, no problem; anything not a directive (C + SQL) is swallowed up by `CODE` as arbitrary text for later processing.

```
#define DEBUG  /* directive */

/* below is all <CODE> */
int main(){
   int x;
   EXEC SQL Select * from PRODUCTS;
}
```

### Problem

The parser fails on a handful of source files having SQL statements with temp table references: `TABLE#temp_table`, and that's the main issue since `#` is also the prefix for all directives: `#define`, `#include`

```
#define DEBUG
int main(){
   int x;
   EXEC SQL Select * from PRODUCTS#stage;
}                                 ^------------- OH NO!
```

```
   [@0,0:0='#',<1>,1:0]
   [@1,1:7='define ',<7>,1:1]
   [@2,8:12='DEBUG',<32>,1:8]
   [@3,13:13='\n',<35>,1:13]
   [@4,14:67='int x;\nint main(){\n EXEC SQL Select * from PRODUCTS',<2>,2:0] <CODE>
   [@5,68:68='#',<1>,4:35]        <SHARP> , should be <CODE>
   [@6,69:73='stage',<32>,4:36]   <SYMBOL>, should be <CODE>
   [@7,75:75='\n',<35>,4:42]      
   [@8,76:77='}\n',<2>,5:0]       
   [@9,78:77='<EOF>',<-1>,6:0]
```

In the above example, the lexer reads everything from `int x` to `PRODUCTS` as `CODE`, then switches to parsing for directives since the rule for `CODE` excludes `#`, we don't want that. We need the entire `main()` function parsed as `CODE` from `int main()` to `}`.

### Attempts

I tried using parser predicates to look ahead and check if the token after `#` starts with a directive name (`define`, `if`, etc), and if true, match that rule.  I don't have much experience with predicates but it wasn't long before I realized this was a dead end since the real issue is in the *lexer*, not the parser.

```
text
    : code 
    | {_input.LT(2).getText().startsWith("define")}? '#' directive (NEW_LINE | EOF)
    ;
```

I tried doing the same in the lexer but `CharStream` has no practical means to look ahead without consuming tokens.

#### Modes?

This problem feels similar to how the XML lexer grammar uses modes for parsing text between `<` `>` tags, so perhaps modes - not predicates, is the right solution here?

### UPDATE 1

Thanks to @kaby76, I used a [predicate](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/2052933fa078c136f601d3d2e82aa758dfa2bfcf/php/PhpLexer.g4#L56C28-L56C58) from PHP lexer grammar to check if characters preceding `#` are non-WS, and if so, it's a *directive*, otherwise it's `CODE` so call *more()* to keep reading.

```
@lexer::members {
    private void directiveORcode(int pos) {
        if(this._input.LA(pos) <= 0 || 
           this._input.LA(pos) == '\r' || 
           this._input.LA(pos) == '\n')
         
           this.mode(DIRECTIVE_MODE);
        else
           this.more();
    }
}

SHARP:    '#' {this.directiveORcode(-2);} ;
```

Which produces the following; @4,@5 showing correct token type `CODE`, very nice.

```
   [@0,0:0='#',<1>,1:0]
   [@1,1:7='define ',<7>,1:1]
   [@2,8:12='DEBUG',<32>,1:8]
   [@3,13:13='\n',<35>,1:13]
   [@4,14:51='int x;\nEXEC SQL SELECT * from PRODUCTS',<2>,2:0]
   [@5,52:59='#stage;\n',<2>,3:31]
   [@6,60:59='<EOF>',<-1>,4:0]
```

Comment: The real problem is that `#` for https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/2052933fa078c136f601d3d2e82aa758dfa2bfcf/objc/two-step-processing/ObjectiveCPreprocessorLexer.g4 requires a semantic predicate. The pound-sign (`#`) must begin without any preceding non-WS characters before the beginning of the line. The "spec" for the language should say something like this. Check out https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/2052933fa078c136f601d3d2e82aa758dfa2bfcf/php/PhpLexer.g4#L56 for something similar. The grammar is wrong, and I haven't updated grammars with directives to reflect this.

Comment: That php predicate for Shebang - `{this.IsNewLineOrStart(-2) }?` was the key! see update. You should make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.